# 3d line interpolation using matlab

Tags: matlab, interpolation

I am a beginner in matlab and I would like to extract some point values along z-axis.

[image]

I have a 3d line information as shown in above figure.
Using this data set, I would like to extract x, y values when z has integer value like 105, 104, 103, 102,,,,,,.

How can I solve this problem?
Is there anybody know this problem?
Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the 1d-interpolation function [`interp1`](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html) for interpolating both x- and y- values (using a method of your choice), each parametrized by the z-values, and evaluate them at your desired z-values.

Example:

```
% generate some data
z = 1:200;
x = sin(z/20);
y = cos(z/30);
plot3(x,y,z,'o-')

% define the points where you want to evaluate your data
desiredZ = [102,103];

%interpolate each component
interpX = interp1(z,x,desiredZ);
interpY = interp1(z,y,desiredZ);
```